# Batch multiple plots in R

Tags: r, plot

Good evening,

I am trying to make an R script which generates one different plot from every .txt file, which has been previously generated in batch by an instrument, and located in the same folder of the script.

I am very inexpert in R and programming in general (1-2 months of practise so far).

The .txt files have two columns each, V1 and V2, with no header.

Here is the code that I have generated:

````
```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsci)

fileNames <- list.files(getwd(), full.names = T, pattern="txt")
#print(fileNames)

Speed_selection <- grep('speed', fileNames, value=TRUE)

length <- length(Speed_selection)

i <- 1

if(i<=length){
  #print(Speed_selection[i])
  Speed <- read.table((Speed_selection[i]), header=F, sep="")

  p <- ggplot(Speed)+geom_line(aes(V1,V2))
  ggsave("plot.pdf", p)

  i=i+1
  i
} else {
  print("Finished")
}
```
````

My thoughts before generating the code were the following:

- I obtain the list of all txt files in a folder. I check the list, and it prints only the txt files.
- I select only the .txt files that have "speed" in the name.
- I assign the value of 1 to i
- The if loop: if i is <= than the number of the selected files

  - read the i^th file in the file selection (with i = 1, first file)
  - I make the plot I save it the directory
  - I increase i by 1.

So the next round will start with i = 2

The problem is, I only get one plot (corresponding to the first file), as the loop is not going through all the length of the "Speed_selection".

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for the help,

best regards.

Comment: If you had a loop it would overwrite "plot.pdf" every single time, so you're only going to get a single output.  You would need to have a `for` at the start to implement the loop. Also, what is the `p <- plot(V2~V1, Speed, "l")` after the `ggsave` accomplishing?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I thought so, but it is only plotting the first file of the selection list, not the second ( as it would occur as a consequence of the overwrite)... Thank you also for the correction on the plot after ggsave. I was trying to see if the normal plot function would have solve the problem. I correct it in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using a helper function and `purrr` since you're already using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsci)

print_plots <- function(x) {

  data <- read.table(x, header=F, sep="")

  file_name <- sprintf("%s plot.pdf", basename(x))

   p <- ggplot(data) + 
         geom_line(aes(V1,V2))

  ggsave(file_name, p)

}

fileNames <- list.files(getwd(), full.names = T, pattern="txt")

Speed_selection <- grep('speed', fileNames, value = TRUE)

walk(Speed_selection, ~print_plots(.x))
```

Or in a pipe:

```
list.files(getwd(), full.names = T, pattern="txt") %>%
       grep('speed', ., value = TRUE) %>%
       walk(Speed_selection, ~print_plots(.x))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I have no idea why. Back to the textbooks... Thank you for the help!

Comment: Under the hood, `purrr` is using the `apply` family of functions.  These functions will apply another function to each element of a list/vector.  The `walk` function uses `sapply` but produces no output to the environment.  Essentially it walks the function through the list of files, and the side-effects of the `print_plots` helper function write you plots to pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are over-complicating this. Wouldn't the following accomplish the same thing?

```
for( x in list.files(getwd(), full.names = T, pattern="\\.txt"))
{
  Speed <- read.table(x, header=F, sep="")

  p <- ggplot(Speed) +
    geom_line(aes(V1,V2))

  ggsave(p,filename=paste0(gsub("\\..*","",x),"_plot.pdf"))
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this gave me the following error: "Error: `device` must be NULL, a string or a function."

Comment: I didn't explicitly state which was the `ggplot2` object and which was the filename. What about now?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now it works. Had an issue with a file name (had 0.5 in the name), but you couldn't know it in advance. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Of course. I'm curious how this differs from the other solution?